# Disable the jquery multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can i disable the multiselected plugin

[jquery multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#enabledisable)

in the above link its toggled i want to enable or disable depending upon a particular condition.

tnx for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know how much JavaScript you know, but `$widget.multiselect('disable');` will disable the selector (stored in the variable `$widget`). And by replacing `disable` with `enable` you can enable it.

So just run the function with the correct disable/enable setting and you can do it based on any condition.

Terw

Answer (score 21):

```
$("#mymultiselect").multiselect("disable");
```

should do the trick.

**HTML**:

```
<select id="test001" multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option> 
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option> 
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option> 
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option> 
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#test001").multiselect({
    minWidth: 300,
    height: 150,
    header: false,
    noneSelectedText: "Select",
    selectedList: 3
});
```

Calling `$("#test001").multiselect("disable");` will disabled the multiselect.

Here's an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/cSq2L)

Answer (score 2):

if you change  `find("input:checked").length > 3`
you can possible to select 3 value For ur wish you can change the.. value and get... your answer

```
  if( $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 2 ){
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the original fiddle posted earlier adding an enable button as well for quicker reference.
http://jsfiddle.net/cSq2L/180/

```
$("#test001").multiselect({
        minWidth: 300,
        height: 150,
        header: false,
        noneSelectedText: "Select",
        selectedList: 3
    });


$("#changeStatus").click(function()
   {
   $("#test001").multiselect("disable");
   });                   

   $("#changeStatuss").click(function()
   {
   $("#test001").multiselect("enable");
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be able to help you in a long run,Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JOKER123/bzuyp6xt/5/

```
function bs_muliselect_init(selector = '') {
  var selector = (selector != '') ? selector : '.bs_multiselect';
  var selector_index = $(selector).index();
  var selector_container_class = selector + '_container' + selector_index;
  selector_container_class = selector_container_class.replace(/[.#]/g, '');

  $(selector).multiselect({
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    optionClass: function(element) {
      return selector_container_class;
    },
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
      var max_limit = $(selector).attr('data-max_limit');
      var max_limit_msg = $(selector).attr('data-max_limit_msg');
      var selectedOptions = $(selector + ' option:selected');
      if (max_limit != undefined && max_limit != '' && !isNaN(max_limit)) {
        if (selectedOptions.length == max_limit) {
          alert(max_limit_msg);
          // Disable all other checkboxes.
          var nonSelectedOptions = $(selector + ' option').filter(function() {
            return !$(this).is(':selected');
          });

          nonSelectedOptions.each(function() {
            var input = $('.' + selector_container_class + ' input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
            input.prop('disabled', true);
            input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
          });
        } else {

          // Enable all checkboxes.
          $(selector + ' option').each(function() {
            var input = $('.' + selector_container_class + ' input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
            input.prop('disabled', false);
            input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: will remember that next time. sorry for this time.